# How can Pillow and MATLAB Runtime be used together on macOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, python-imaging-library

In order to use the MATLAB runtime on macOS, the [`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` must be updated to point to the MATLAB Runtime](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/python/install-a-matlab-compiler-sdk-python-package.html).

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/runtime/maci64:/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/sys/os/maci64:/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64
```

Then, to use [`Pillow`, it must be installed](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#macos-installation):

```
$ pip3 install Pillow
```

When running the following code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

print('Hello World')
```

The following error is shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
  File "/Users/user/venv/py-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/venv/py-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/.dylibs/libtiff.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user/venv/py-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _imaging.cpython-36m-darwin.so requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libtiff.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0
```

If run without the first `export` command, `Pillow` works fine, but I can't find out a way to get both to work at once. The MATLAB Runtime is exporting an older version of `libtiff` that `Pillow` (even though it's install via a binary wheel) is loading:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64/libtiff.5.dylib
```

System configuration

- macOS 10.11.6
- Python 3.6.4 installed via Homebrew
- Pillow 5.0.0
- MATLAB Runtime 2017b

Comment: Comment from Pillow developer: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3052